# How can I make an Angular2 "deep" css class take precedence?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular2-template, css-specificity

In the styles block of my top level component, I define a `/deep/` css class that sets the margins for any items that will appear within its ng-content. How can I make that css class take precedence - even if a child component applies its own css class that has different margins defined.

For example:

ParentComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-parent',
    styles: [`
        /deep/ .child-item { /* I WANT THIS TO TAKE PRECEDENCE */
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <div>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        <div>
    `
})
export class ParentComponent {}
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-child',
    styles: [`
        .less-important-class { /* THESE MARGINS SHOULD BE IGNORED IN CONFLICTS */
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <button type="button" class="less-important-class child-item">My Little Button</button>
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

I think since child-item appears first in the compiled style sheet, less-important-class has higher css specificity and wins out in any conflicts between the two classes. How can I give child-item a higher precedence?

Comment: As always, you can give the rules that belong to less specific selector (deep) a higher priority with `!important`.

Comment: adding !important doesn't help in this case because the way angular works it makes sure that child components styles take precedence whatever you do.

Comment: I found that using the `:host` selector before my `/deep/` css class gave that class precedence over css classes defined in child components. As long as those components didn't also use the `:host` selector.

Answer (score 1):

/deep/ is used to over ride parents style so say you want to change margin of a div in parent you can use /deep/  {margin: **px}

As far as I know you define styles in child component when you don't want parent component to interfere with styles of child components. If you want style of parent to be taking precedence then I would say don't define those styles in child. Which means in your case, don't specify margin in styles defined in child component.

Another way is don't define those stlyes either in Parent or child but create a new global stylesheet and add there only global styles of course you need to refer that stylesheet in index.html So in your case I would remove margin from styles of both parent and child and add it to say styles.css and refer styles.css in index.html

Comment: In the documentation it says `We can use the /deep/ selector to force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views. The /deep/ selector works to any depth of nested components, and it applies both to the view children and the content children of the component.`

Comment: But I see what you're saying. My problem is that sometimes the child component appears outside the parent component, and when it does the margins need to be different. So I was hoping to have the parent change them if the child occurs inside it.

Comment: Well in that case I think, having a container in parent surrounding child component should help you to apply the margins.